# Is a Jordan Curve always closed?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I understand that the very **[definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JordanCurve.html)** of a Jordan Curve includes that it be a closed curve. However, I am reading a paper written by E. Hopf in 1950 in which he proves a theorem by Bernstein.

In this paper, we are working on the $\mathbb{R^2}$ plane and he mentions the existence of a Jordan curve $\big( x(t), y(t) \big)$ for which $x(t) \rightarrow \pm \infty$ as $t\rightarrow \pm\infty$. What confuses me is the fact that this curve will not be closed under normal circumstances.
(I can show more of the context of the paper but I have chosen not to to keep things short)

---

My thoughts on possible explanations:

- This is a closed curve if we include the point at infinity, however it is not explicitly mentioned that we are working on the plane $\mathbb{R^2}\cup \{ \infty \}$.
- Hopf simply means a continuous curve when he talks about a Jordan curve (ie, not necessarily smooth).

What do you think?

Comment: Taking your points in reverse order: smoothness is not required in the [usual definition of a Jordan curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem), so I don't understand your second point; depending on the context, it could make sense for Hopf to treat a curve with a point at infinity as a Jordan curve because it divides the plain into two connected regions (so we'd need to know the context to help).

Comment: @RobArthan yes, adding the parenthesis was too much on my part, but my point was that a Jordan curve is any continuous curve for Hopf, as, like you mention, smoothness is not usually required anyways.
To add more context, Hopf is "mending" a hole that was left in Bernstein's Theorem on Minimal Surfaces. even though it is a geometric statement, it is usually treated with the help of Complex Analysis tools such as Liouville.

Answer (score 1):

> "this curve will not be closed under normal circumstances."

Such a curve actually is necessarily closed. First, since $x(t) \to \pm\infty$ as $t \to \pm\infty$, we know that the curve extends to a continuous function $\gamma : S^1 \to S^2$ (where $S^1 = \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ is the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ and $S^2 = \mathbb{R}^2 \cup \{\infty\}$ is the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^2$) such that $\gamma(\infty) = \infty$. Since $S^1$ is compact and $S^2$ is Hausdorff, $\gamma(S^1)$ is closed in $S^2$. The image of the original curve is just $\gamma(S^1) \cap (S^2 \setminus \{\infty\})$ as a subset of $S^2 \setminus \{\infty\} = \mathbb{R}^2$. By definition of the subspace topology, the image of the original curve is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I understand, however, in this context, $\gamma: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ is a closed curve if $\gamma(a) = \gamma(b)$. This is where my confusion arises from. If we include the point at infinity then we can have $\gamma:[-\infty, \infty]: \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2} \cup \{ \infty \}$ is closed if $\gamma(-\infty) = \gamma(\infty) = \infty$

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what you meant! My mistake – I thought you were asking for a proof that the image of $t \mapsto (x(t), y(t)) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is closed. In any case, you're right: in order for this curve to be a closed curve, we ought to view it as a map $[-\infty, \infty] \to \mathbb{R}^2 \cup \{\infty\}$.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. Further on in the paper, Hopf mentions the addition of the points $x = \pm \infty$ to the boundary of an open (and unbounded) set. I took this to mean that we are allowed to consider the point at infinity as part of the plane.